# Array to string conversion in class.settings.php at 833 during PHP 7.4 Code Upgrade

Tags: php, arrays

I had zero knowledge of php until I was told by my hosting company that I had to update my websites code to be compatible with php 7.4 and mysqli.I am quite proud of myself in that I managed to fix at least 300 errors before having to reach out for help to another coder. But with his busy schedule I hate bothering him when I get stuck. He barely is able to make a little time one day a week. I believe I have finally came to the light at the end of the tunnel. I am encountering two errors left as of now. These two have me so confused. I have googled trying to find answers but can't comprehend exactly what to do since I don't understand the php language. I am hoping someone here would be so kind as to help me. I would love to find a person that has skype that loves teaching new people and can help me if I come across something else. I hate flooding this community if I run into a error here and there. I just hope that after fixing these final 2 no more appear. It seemed like I would fix one and ten more would come about. Im thinking this has to come to an end sooner or later.

The code has the line number next to the error.

ERROR #1:

> Array to string conversion in class.settings.php at 833

```
private function ManageReturnsSettings($messages=array())
    {

        $GLOBALS['Message'] = GetFlashMessageBoxes();

        foreach ($this->all_vars as $var) {
            if (is_string(GetConfig($var)) || is_numeric(GetConfig($var))) {
                $GLOBALS[$var] = isc_html_escape(GetConfig($var));
            } elseif (is_array(GetConfig($var))) {
        LINE 833> $GLOBALS[$var.'Area'] = isc_html_escape(implode("\r\n", GetConfig($var)));
            }
        }

        // Are returns enabled?
        if (GetConfig('EnableReturns')) {
            $GLOBALS['IsEnableReturns'] = "checked=\"checked\"";
        }

        // Can store credits be issued?
        if (GetConfig('ReturnCredits')) {
            $GLOBALS['IsReturnCredits'] = "checked=\"checked\"";
        }

        if (GetConfig('EmailOwnerOnReturn')) {
            $GLOBALS['IsReturnNotifyOwner'] = "checked=\"checked\"";
        }

        if (GetConfig('SendReturnConfirmation')) {
            $GLOBALS['IsReturnNotifyCustomer'] = "checked=\"checked\"";
        }

        if (GetConfig('NotifyOnReturnStatusChange')) {
            $GLOBALS['IsReturnNotifyStatusChange'] = "checked=\"checked\"";
        }

        $this->template->display('settings.returns.manage.tpl');
    }
```

Error #2:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Core.php at 391

```
// add multibyte extensions if possible
if (function_exists('mb_get_info')) {
    function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
    {
        return is_string($thing) ? mb_strlen($thing, $env->getCharset()) : count($thing);
    }

    function twig_upper_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        if (null !== ($charset = $env->getCharset())) {
        LINE 391>    return mb_strtoupper($string, $charset);
        }

        return strtoupper($string);
    }

    function twig_lower_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        if (null !== ($charset = $env->getCharset())) {
            return mb_strtolower($string, $charset);
        }

        return strtolower($string);
    }

    function twig_title_string_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        if (null !== ($charset = $env->getCharset())) {
            return mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, $charset);
        }

        return ucwords(strtolower($string));
    }

    function twig_capitalize_string_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        if (null !== ($charset = $env->getCharset())) {
            return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $charset)).
                         mb_strtolower(mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string), $charset), $charset);
        }

        return ucfirst(strtolower($string));
    }
}
// and byte fallback
else
{
    function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
    {
        return is_string($thing) ? strlen($thing) : count($thing);
    }

    function twig_title_string_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        return ucwords(strtolower($string));
    }

    function twig_capitalize_string_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($string));
    }
}

function twig_ensure_traversable($seq)
{
    if (is_array($seq) || (is_object($seq) && $seq instanceof Traversable)) {
        return $seq;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

function twig_test_sameas($value, $test)
{
    return $value === $test;
}

function twig_test_none($value)
{
    return null === $value;
}

function twig_test_divisibleby($value, $num)
{
    return 0 == $value % $num;
}

function twig_test_even($value)
{
    return $value % 2 == 0;
}

function twig_test_odd($value)
{
    return $value % 2 == 1;
}

function twig_test_constant($value, $constant)
{
    return constant($constant) === $value;
}

function twig_test_defined($name, $context)
{
    return array_key_exists($name, $context);
}

function twig_test_empty($value)
{
    return null === $value || false === $value || '' === (string) $value;
}
```

Comment: If you are using Drupal here is the link to fix one of your errors: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/issues/1914

Comment: I'm not using Drupal. It may work though. I'll try it.